# Dual Boot Issue: Arch Linux SSD Not Recognized in BIOS After Windows Installation

Tags: linux, boot, windows, ssd, bios

I’m currently facing an issue with my dual boot setup. I have two NVMe SSDs: a 1TB SSD with Arch Linux and GRUB configured, and a newly installed 4TB SSD with Windows.

To avoid any complications during the Windows installation, I temporarily removed the Linux SSD. After confirming that Windows was functioning correctly, I reconnected the Linux SSD. However, upon reboot, the Linux SSD was no longer recognized in the BIOS, preventing me from booting into Arch Linux. Interestingly, the Linux SSD is visible in the Windows Disk Management utility.

In my previous setup, I had both Linux and Windows on dual boot without any issues. The only difference this time is that I installed Windows after Linux. Could the installation order be causing this problem?

Based on my research, it seems that I might need to create an Arch Live USB, boot from it, mount my Linux system from chroot, and reconfigure GRUB. However, as I’m relatively new to GRUB and boot-loading, I’m unsure if this is the correct approach.

Could anyone confirm if this is the right solution? If so, could you provide a step-by-step guide? I’m cautious about proceeding alone due to a past experience where I accidentally formatted the wrong disk during a Linux re-installation.

Comment: A lot of UEFI forget UEFI boot entries when a drive is removed. They usually do find Windows entry in ESP and boot it. You may just need new UEFI boot entry. You can use efibootmgr or reinstall grub will will also add the entry. Do not know Arch but see `man efibootmgr` See grub install command with efibootmgr: https://wiki.archlinux.org Or: UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380/title/GRUB